How to package openCV android sdk with an android plugin?
I need to create an android plugin for Godot Game engine. My android plugin needs an openCV feature. I have managed to integrate openCV in my android project using this tutorial but I need openCV in my android plugin as well, so I added implementation(project(":openCV")) in my android plugin's build.gradle as well, I need to export my plugin to Android Archive (aar) format so for that I use ./gradlew assemble command but the problem is my aar does not contain openCV sdk even though I have added implementation(project(":openCV")) in my android plugin's build.gradle
To package openCV in my plugin's aar file I tried adding following code to my android plugin's build.gradle but none of them worked
First attempt:
packagingOptions {
        resources.pickFirsts.add("opencv_folder/**")
    }

Second attempt:
packagingOptions {
        resources.pickFirsts.add("**/*")
    }

Third attempt:
 packagingOptions {
        jniLibs.pickFirsts.add("**/*.so")
    }

Fourth attempt:
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs("path_to_opencv_folder")
        }
    }

Fifth attempt:
 packagingOptions {
        jniLibs.pickFirsts.add("**/*.so")
    }

Sixth attempt:
 packagingOptions {
        jniLibs.pickFirsts.add("lib/**/*.so")
    }

Seventh attempt:
packagingOptions {
        jniLibs.pickFirsts.add("**/opencv_module_folder/**/*.so")
    }

Eighth attempt:
 sourceSets {
        named("main") {
            java.srcDirs(file("../opencv_module_folder/src/main/java"))
        }
    }

Nineth attempt:
sourceSets {
        getByName("main").java.srcDirs = files("../opencv_module_folder/src/main/java")
    }

Tenth attempt:
packagingOptions {
        // Include all necessary files from OpenCV
        from(project(":openCV")) {
            include("**/*.so")
        }
    }

Eleventh attempt:
tasks {
        val createAar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
            archiveBaseName.set("YourPluginName")
            archiveExtension.set("aar")
            destinationDirectory.set(file("path/to/output/folder"))
            from android.sourceSets.main.java.classes
            from android.sourceSets.main.resources
            from('openCV/build/outputs/aar') { // include OpenCV AAR file
                include '*.aar'
            }
        }
    }

I am slo little confused what all things do I need from openCV. Do I need just .so files for each android architecture and all the files from the openCV sdk

I think you will need to describe more clearly what you are trying to achieve, and why Gradle is part of it, to get any help. I doubt anyone wants to watch a YouTube video

Seems similar to: Create one aar from multi module library in android

Fat-aar is no longer maintained, any other solution @MorrisonChang

Not that I am aware of, other than perhaps moving/copying all dependency resources & source code into your library project. See: library with bundles dependencies (fat aar) and Android Studio how to package single AAR from multiple library projects? for links to discussions and open issue ticket.

Isn't OpenCV available in Maven and can be imported like implementation 'org.opencv:opencv:4.9.0'? In this case, it should be bundled into your AAR.

@jokuskay yes but that's not from the official opencv team, it is published by some third party

Have you check this link
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.opencv/opencv/overview and code from here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/download/4.9.0/opencv-4.9.0-android-sdk.zip

@BraveEvidence can you post your project level gradle file ?

@BobSmith Here is the code https://github.com/BraveEvidence/GodotOpenCV . Also if I try to use opencv from maven I get this error now after merging with Godot https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject-6952a.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202024-05-03%20at%209.45.28%E2%80%AFPM.png?alt=media&token=b8a484c5-04d1-4eaf-86f6-e4c6c5e306d5

@BraveEvidence in MyGodotProject folder there is no android project and MyAndroidProject folder is not clickable. We can do one more thing can you post project level and app level gradle by editing the question.

For generating AAR you need to make some changes in your project.
1. Configure the build.gradle file:
a). Go to the "build.gradle" file under your library module.
Remove :


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Add the following line within the android block. 


plugin 'com.android.library'

Reason: To convert an app module to a library module.
More info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html
b). Remove applicationId from app.gradle.
It does this by tipping the build system Gradle that the project needs to be viewed as Android library.
2. Output of the build process:
Upon completion of the library build, you will then move and package your module into the build/outputs/aar/[your module] directory.
In build.gradle file you define the config for lib by varying minimum SDK version and dependencies.
Yet another link between the .aar file and one of the applications is made through the library. Then, the library declares the .aar file as a dependency in the build.gradle file of the app.
3. Execute command to generate aar :
your-opencv-project
    |- build
        |- outputs
            |- aar
                |- project-debug.aar
                 - project-release.aar

If these files don't exist start a build with command :
gradlew assemble

4. Import .aar in your project
Finally, all we need to do is to add the project as a dependency into our build.gradle file like so:
dependencies {
    implementation(name:'OpenCV', ext:'aar')
}

Reference of open cv sample project :

Downloaded from GitHub

The provided links offer further details:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html explains Gradle tasks

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library provides the official documentation on the AAR format used for Android libraries.


Refrences for Open CV
https://opencv.org/opencv4android-samples/
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.opencv/opencv/overview
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk
